# How to add an additional digit in multiple file names in linux terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rename, batch-rename

I have around 1800 files with their names as follows,

```
fluxes_22.4625_87.1875  
fluxes_22.7125_86.6625  
fluxes_22.8375_86.5375  
fluxes_22.9375_86.3625  
fluxes_23.0375_86.2125  
fluxes_23.3625_86.2375
fluxes_22.4875_86.9625
...
...
```

I need to add an additional digit zero to convert the file names as follows

```
fluxes_22.46250_87.18750  
fluxes_22.71250_86.66250  
fluxes_22.83750_86.53750  
fluxes_22.93750_86.36250  
fluxes_23.03750_86.21250  
fluxes_23.36250_86.23750
fluxes_22.48750_86.96250
...
...
```

Though this can be done in MATLAB easily, how to do it in LINUX terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If all these files are in the same folder you can try something like that:

```
for file in $(ls /path/to/files) ; do mv $file "$file"0 ; done
```

this will iterate over the files and rename them with 0 at the end.

Comment: Thanks Mani, but here I need to add "0" at two positions not at the end only.